# How to get svn file lock time out?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am using the Tortoise SVN. I had to change a source file and some one already locked the file.I tried to "get the lock" it also failed.I would like to know what would be the solution if someone locked a file and left it locked for some time (say 1 day).Would like to know any techniques or methods like timeout exists to override the lock.
The clean up action is a global one done in a folder, I don't want any other file lock status  to be affected by my actions other than the intended one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Folder is locked and I can't unlock it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018928/folder-is-locked-and-i-cant-unlock-it)

Comment: Just break the lock: https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html#tsvn-dug-locking-how

Comment: This is what I did in the end. It would be nice if they had some thing better than breaking the co-worker lock.